# postgressql - ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "column_name"

Tags: postgresql, function, runtime-error

I am a newbie to PostgreSQL. I have created below PostgreSQL function and getting an error  as below:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "expenseid"
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertorupdateinvoice(invoice jsonb)
     RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
Declare _invoiceid bigint;
begin
  --Consider all columns in specialist table as character varying and code column as integer.
  insert into invoicemaster (expenseid, invoiceno, transactiondate, totalinvoiceamount, invoicedoc, createdby, createdon)
  select j.invoice->>'expenseid'::bigint, 
         j.invoice->>'invoiceno', 
         (j.invoice->>'transactiondate')::date, 
         j.invoice->>'totalinvoiceamount'::double precision, 
         j.invoice->>'invoicedoc', 
         j.invoice->>'createdby'::bigint, 
         (j.invoice->>'createdon')::timestamp without time zone
  from jsonb_array_elements(invoice) as j(invoice)
  returning invoiceid into _invoiceid;
  
  insert into lineitemmaster (invoiceid, transactiondate, merchantname, amount, departmentid, policyid, itemdescription, 
                              itemcategory, itemtype, status, isrejected, createdby, createdon)
  select _invoiceid::bigint, 
        x.invoice->>'transactiondate'::date, 
        x.invoice->>'merchantname', 
        x.invoice->>'amount'::double precision, 
        x.invoice->>'departmentid'::integer, 
        x.invoice->>'policyid'::integer, 
        x.invoice->>'itemdescription', 
        x.invoice->>'itemcategory'::integer, 
        x.invoice->>'itemtype'::integer, 
        x.invoice->>'status'::boolean, 
        x.invoice->>'isrejected'::boolean, 
        x.invoice->>'createdby'::bigint, 
        (x.invoice->>'createdon')::timestamp without time zone
  from jsonb_array_elements(invoice ->'lineitems') as x;
end;
$BODY$;
```

I am executing function as below:

```
select * from insertorupdateinvoice('{"expenseid":1,
    "invoiceno":"04012022",
    "transactiondate":"2022-01-04",
    "totalinvoiceamount":1000.00,
    "invoicedoc":"invoicedoc",
    "createdby":"1",
    "list":[
      {"transactiondate":"2022-01-01", "merchantname":"Apple", "amount":"100.50", "departmentid":"1","policyid":"1", "itemdescription":"iphone 14 pro max", "itemcategory":"55", "itemtype":"499", "status":"true", "isrejected":"false", "createdby":"1"},
      {"transactiondate":"2022-01-02", "merchantname":"Samsung", "amount":"1050.35", "departmentid":"2","policyid":"2", "itemdescription":"samsung galaxy tab", "itemcategory":"40", "itemtype":"50", "status":"true", "isrejected":"false", "createdby":"1"},
      {"transactiondate":"2022-01-03", "merchantname":"Big bazar", "amount":"555.75", "departmentid":"3","policyid":"3", "itemdescription":"grocerry", "itemcategory":"5", "itemtype":"90", "status":"false", "isrejected":"false", "createdby":"1"}
    ]}');
```

error I am getting as below:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "expenseid"
LINE 2:   select j.invoice->>'expenseid'::bigint, 
                             ^
QUERY:  insert into invoicemaster (expenseid, invoiceno, transactiondate, totalinvoiceamount, invoicedoc, createdby, createdon)
  select j.invoice->>'expenseid'::bigint, 
         j.invoice->>'invoiceno', 
         (j.invoice->>'transactiondate')::date, 
         j.invoice->>'totalinvoiceamount'::double precision, 
         j.invoice->>'invoicedoc', 
         j.invoice->>'createdby'::bigint, 
         (j.invoice->>'createdon')::timestamp without time zone
  from jsonb_array_elements(invoice) as j(invoice)
  returning invoiceid
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insertorupdateinvoice(jsonb) line 5 at SQL statement
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: ```(j.invoice->>'expenseid')::bigint``` maybe?

Comment: In Your function call input jsonb:  there is no key "lineitems", there is no key 'createdon'.

Comment: now getting error as below:
```
ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into invoicemaster (expenseid, invoiceno, transactiondate, totalinvoiceamount, invoicedoc, createdby)
  select (j.invoice->>'expenseid')::bigint, 
         (j.invoice->>'invoiceno')::character, 
         (j.invoice->>'transactiondate')::date, 
         (j.invoice->>'totalinvoiceamount')::double precision, 
         (j.invoice->>'invoicedoc')::character, 
         (j.invoice->>'createdby')::bigint
  from jsonb_array_elements(invoice) as j(invoice)
  returning invoiceid"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got an solution for this one as below as do not use jsonb name while extracting the values.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insertorupdateinvoice(
        invoice jsonb)
        RETURNS void
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    AS $BODY$
    Declare _invoiceid bigint;
    begin
      insert into invoicemaster (expenseid, invoiceno, transactiondate, totalinvoiceamount, invoicedoc, createdby, createdon)
      values ( (invoice->>'expenseid') :: bigint, 
               (invoice->>'invoiceno') :: character, 
               (invoice->>'transactiondate') :: date, 
               (invoice->>'totalinvoiceamount') :: double precision, 
               (invoice->>'invoicedoc') :: character, 
               (invoice->>'createdby') :: bigint,
               NOW()
             )
      returning invoiceid into _invoiceid;

      insert into lineitemmaster (invoiceid, transactiondate, merchantname, amount, departmentid, policyid, itemdescription, 
                                  itemcategory, itemtype, status, isrejected, createdby, createdon)
      select _invoiceid::bigint, 
            (x->>'transactiondate')::date, 
            x->>'merchantname', 
            (x->>'amount')::double precision, 
            (x->>'departmentid')::integer, 
            (x->>'policyid')::integer, 
            x->>'itemdescription', 
            (x->>'itemcategory')::integer, 
            (x->>'itemtype')::integer, 
            (x->>'status')::boolean, 
            (x->>'isrejected')::boolean, 
            (x->>'createdby')::bigint,
            NOW()
      from jsonb_array_elements(invoice ->'lineitems') as x;
    end;
    $BODY$;
```